# responsive cards bootstrap4

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

I have two column inside row ,
col-sm-9 col-xs-11 for my main 
col-sm-3 col-xs-1 sidebar-offcanvas for my side bar.
inside of my main col I have cards to display my post, but when I Put my cards inside of other cols to display 3 post in one row my pagination button come to inside of my cards and display one card in each row.

```css
.card {
    float: right;
    width: 31%;
 margin: 5px 10px 10px 10px;
}
.card-img{
 height: 200px;
}
.card-title{
  font-size: 16px;
  text-align: right;
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-right: 5px;
}
.card-title a{
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #343a40;
}
.card-author{
 color: #908E99;
 font-size: 11px;
 margin-right: 5px;
}
.card-author a{
 text-decoration: none;
}
.card-author a:hover{
 color: #343a40;
}
.card-date{
    color: #908E99;
 font-size: 11px;
 margin-right: 5px;
}
.card-date a{
 text-decoration: none;
}
.card-content{
    float: right;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 5px 10px 0;
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 2;
}
.readmore{
 float: right;

}
.readmore a{
 background: #343a40 none repeat scroll 0 0;
 color: #ffffff;
 border: 1px solid #1b1c20;
    border-radius: 3px;
 padding: 2px 10px;
 margin-right: 1px;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="container-fluid">
     <div class="row my-row">
             <div class="col-sm-9 col-xs-11" id="main">
                    <div class="card">
                    <img class="card-img" src="admin/upload/<?php echo $result['image']; ?>"alt="Card image"/>
                     <div class="card-block">
                      <h4 class="card-title">
                      <a href="post.php?id=<?php echo $result['id']; ?>"><?php echo $result['title']; ?></a>
                    </h4> 
                                    <h6 class="card-author"> توسط : <a href="#"><?php echo $result['author']; ?></a>
                    </h6>
                    <h6 class="card-date"><?php echo $fm->formatDate($result['date']); ?></h6><br/>    
                       <div class="card-text">
                         <?php echo $fm->textShorten($result['body'], 400); ?>
                                       </div>
                       <div class="card-footer">
                         <a href="post.php?id=<?php echo $result['id']; ?>">ادامه مطلب</a>
                       </div>         
                     </div>    
                           </div>
```

Comment: The question isn't very clear. Can you clarify, clean up the code and create a minimal example?

Comment: that's my index.php ,in  row , col's are my post content , and how can we make responsive card element?

Comment: in small screen my pagination move to side of the cards and my cards are not responsive in small screen , so I want my pagination stay bottom of my cards and dont move top , second is making responsive cards display ,in small screen